# Using Event Grid on IIS or locally

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

We have started using Azure's Event Grid on our Dev site, however we have a few developers who work on their local machine. I was wondering if there was a way of setting it up so that we could have event grid running locally on each machine rather than each local area connecting to the dev environment?

Answer (score 1):

I think connecting the developer machines to an Azure-hosted Event Grid is the best option here - I am not aware of an Event Grid emulator. However, if you are running Kubernetes in your company, you might consider running [Event Grid on Kubernetes with Azure Arc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/kubernetes/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

Comment: From what Ive read online I think this is our only option, just wanted to post incase someone had come across a better way. Thanks for the help